# Jupyter notebook command doesn't work following Python upgrade to 3.12.0

Tags: python, jupyter, homebrew, version, pyenv

I had been having issues with python (when running `python --version`, I would get Python 3.7.4, but would get 3.11 when running `python3 --version`). I now cannot run `jupyter notebook` following  upgrading python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaGag.jpg)

I tried a bunch of things to upgrade Python and I used these (https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac) steps to upgrade to 3.12 using pyenv.
Now, however, jupyter notebook doesn't even run and I'm running into a very nasty error.

Comment: different versions of Python don't share modules. If you updated `Python` then you have to install all modules again. ie. `python3.12 -m pip install jupyter`, etc. BTW: sometimes some modules may not work with the newest Python because authors may need time to change code in modules - and it is good to use little older version and wait few months. Or you should have both versions (older and the newest) and from time to time check if all modules already work on the newest version.